# Can't scroll to the bottom of flowlayout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, flowlayoutpanel

[image]

In the image attached you can see that there are 5 panels inside a flowlayout panel. However, i can't scroll to the bottom of the flowlayout panel, to see the last added panel entirely.

Any ideea why?

Comment: Set the panel's AutoScroll property to True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it seems that i had the wrong size of the flowlayout panel, resizing fixed it!